# HSV Clor space help for OpenCV project

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

I am working on detecting the Ball on Table Football. A screenshot of the game is:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsvxqlb358sshob/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-28%20at%2014.24.53.png

I am trying to use the following code:

```
hsv_min = cv.Scalar (0,0,100)
hsv_max = cv.Scalar (60,4.3,100)
cv.InRangeS (hsvframe, hsv_min, hsv_max, threshpic)
```

I am confused with the color range for the Ball on HSV color space. Can any one tell me what can be the color range in HSV scaler ?

Comment: You'll have to convert an image of the ball to HSV and have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the C API, it's 
H: 0-360, S: 0-1, V: 0-1. Try using these limits.

Comment: I am using Open CV with Python. I can Detect yellow ball using: hsv_min = cv.Scalar (20,100,100) hsv_max = cv.Scalar (30,255,255) Can you say for that white ball?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Well, try with something like (0-360), (0-50), (180-255) for H,S,V.

Comment: Great, But problem is that, This range detects some yellow and white lines. My expected object is little bit brown. It would great If I could only detect the ball. One more thing, can you explain how you define the ranges? Thank you.

Comment: Here you go: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Hsl-hsv_models.svg/400px-Hsl-hsv_models.svg.png

Comment: As you see, grayscale colors have low saturation and higher variance in hue (due to bias of the camera; ambient lightning). And bright colors have higher value. So that is how I arrived at the numbers I gave you.

Comment: I am in the same problem with the yellow player(https://www.dropbox.com/s/i101gsbn27bjeb6/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-11%20at%2016.04.34.png). Now I want to detect them separately. Can you kindly tell me the hsv color range for the yellow players. Thank you in advance.